# Puppet r10k : Nginx Package

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, puppet

I want to download the latest package/version of Nginx but it seems my code does not pulling the latest Nginx (1.18), any thought that I should add ? here's my code.

```
class nginx {

  package { 'nginx':
    ensure => 'latest',
  }

  service { 'nginx':
    ensure  => running,
    enable  => true,
    require => Package['nginx'],
  }
}
```

Comment: "latest" is defined relative to the package repositories configured on your machine.  If that `Package` resource is being applied successfully to the target machine, then you are getting the latest version of nginx that is presently accessible to it.  That very well might not be the latest one released.

Comment: Additionally, could you clarify how r10k impacts the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

As John Bollinger has pointed out, you'll be getting the latest `nginx` package from the package repository for your version of Ubuntu, which may not be the actual latest version.

If you use the [Forge NGINX Puppet module](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/nginx), you will automatically get the latest version installed from the official NGINX package repository. Just add

```
mod 'puppet-nginx', '3.0.0'
```

to your `Puppetfile` and then rather than writing your own `nginx` class, include the Forge module from your manifest.

```
include nginx
```